# converting columns of list of data frame to factor

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Hi I am giving labels to my data frame manually like below, I have 800 columns to be labeled , after that I am creating a subset of data frame (sub setting of data have many), then applying that data frame to function for calculation.

labels can be different for all chunks , also its very time taking for creating labels one by one for all chunks.

```
data<-data.frame( col1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
                  col2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
                  col3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,1),
                  col4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  col5=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,NA,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)  

data$col5<-factor(data$col5, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Local","Overseas"))

df<- data
df$cc1<-1
df2<- subset(df, col5 == 'Local')
df$cc2<-ifelse(df$col5 == 'Local',1,NA)
lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
ldat<-list("ALL" = df, "Local" =df2)

col_names <- c("col1","col2"...."col4")
    labels <- c("Sales","Ops"...."HR")

make_mutator <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    "factor(", names(faclist)[[x]],
    ",labels=c('",
    paste0(faclist[[x]],
           collapse = "','"
    ), "'))"
  )
}


list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(faclist)),
                              make_mutator)

names(list_of_fac) <- names(faclist)

ldat <- purrr::map(ldat,
                   ~mutate(.,
                           !!!parse_exprs(list_of_fac)))
```

This is perfectly fine and working for me ....but just want new solution if i will give columns and labels separately for columns and labels like

col_names <- c("col1","col2"...."col4")
labels <- c("Sales","Ops"...."HR")

then how can i change my function for this....??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the parsing, an easier option is to use `map2` after looping over the `list` with `map`.  With `map2`, we pass the columns of interest and the labels to be changed based on the named `list` 'faclist'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
ldat1 <- map(ldat, ~  {
     .x[names(faclist)] <- map2(.x %>% 
                             dplyr::select(names(faclist)), 
                         faclist, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
       .x} )
```

-output

```
str(ldat1[[1]])
#'data.frame':  39 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ col1: Factor w/ 1 level "Sales": 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA ...
# $ col2: Factor w/ 1 level "OPS": 1 1 1 1 1 NA NA NA NA 1 ...
# $ col3: Factor w/ 1 level "Management": 1 1 NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA ...
# $ col4: Factor w/ 1 level "HR": 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# $ col5: Factor w/ 2 levels "Local","Overseas": 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
# $ cc1 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ cc2 : num  1 NA 1 1 1 NA 1 NA NA 1 ...
str(ldat1[[2]])
#'data.frame':  18 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ col1: Factor w/ 1 level "Sales": 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 NA ...
#$ col2: Factor w/ 1 level "OPS": 1 1 1 1 NA 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ col3: Factor w/ 1 level "Management": 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# $ col4: Factor w/ 1 level "HR": 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 ...
# $ col5: Factor w/ 2 levels "Local","Overseas": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ cc1 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

---

If it is not a `list`, but two vectors, then just change the `names(faclist)` with the 'col_names' vector and the `list` 'faclist' with `labels` vector

```
ldat1 <- map(ldat, ~  {
     .x[col_names] <- map2(.x %>% 
                             dplyr::select(col_names), 
                         labels, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
       .x} )
```

Comment: actually facelist is no more in my updation , i will have only 
col_names <- c("col1","col2"...."col4") 
labels <- c("Sales","Ops"...."HR")

how can i update function for using with  col_names and labels in place of facelist

Comment: I just updated question, now you will get more understanding

Comment: @sanuali0123 that is easier, just replace the `names(facelist)` with `col_names` and `faclist` with `labels` in the funcion

Comment: @sanuali0123 updated the function.  I would request to change the object name to a different one than a function or argument name

Comment: I tried this but output is wierd
col_names <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
labels <- c("Sales","Ops","admin","HR") 
make_mutator <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    "factor(", col_names[[x]],
    ",labels=c('",
    paste0(labels[[x]],
           collapse = "','"
    ), "'))"
  )
}


list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(col_names)),
                              make_mutator)

names(list_of_fac) <- names(col_names)

ldat <- purrr::map(ldat,
                   ~mutate(.,
                           !!!parse_exprs(list_of_fac)))

Comment: sorry I didn't get you...??

Comment: @sanuali0123 i meant the code you showed in comments is based on your original code and not based on my solution

Comment: yes , it works now my bad sorry....but I should use all of while using select col_names
i skipped one step the but getting warning ....why is that please help me to understand

list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(col_names)),
                              make_mutator)

ldat1 <- map(ldat, ~  {
  .x[col_names] <- map2(.x %>% 
                          dplyr::select(col_names), 
                        labels, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
  .x} )
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(col_names)` instead of `col_names` to silence this message

Comment: I am creating a full function with this but doesn't working
fac_conv <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    "factor(", col_names[[x]],
    ",labels=c('",
    paste0(labels[[x]],
           collapse = "','"
    ), "'))"
  )
}
fac_conv_lapply <- function(data,col_names,labels) {
list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(col_names)),
                              fac_conv)
names(list_of_fac) = names(col_name)
ldat <- map(data, ~  {
  .x[col_names] <- map2(.x %>% 
                          dplyr::select(col_names), 
                        labels, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
  .x} )
}