# Custom function for converting factor of list of data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a function on the basis of my previous question
[converting columns of list of data frame to factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274389/converting-columns-of-list-of-data-frame-to-factor)

but while trying to create a function i am getting error no getting desired output

```
# Sample Data Frame

data<-data.frame( col1=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1),
                  col2=c(1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),
                  col3=c(1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,1),
                  col4=c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  col5=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,NA,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
)  

data$col5<-factor(data$col5, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Local","Overseas"))

# creating a list of dataframes
df<- data
df$cc1<-1
df2<- subset(df, col5 == 'Local')
df$cc2<-ifelse(df$col5 == 'Local',1,NA)
lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
ldat<-list("ALL" = df, "Local" =df2)

###############

# Created function in separate file and sourcing it in my rmd file
#"sub_function"

fac_conv <- function(x) {
  paste0(
    "factor(", col_names[[x]],
    ",labels=c('",
    paste0(labels[[x]],
           collapse = "','"
    ), "'))"
  )
}


fac_conv_lapply <- function(data,col_names,labels) {
  list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(col_names)),
                                fac_conv)
  ldat <- map(data, ~  {
    .x[col_names] <- map2(.x %>% 
                            dplyr::select(col_names), 
                          labels, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
    .x} )
  
}

# NOw I am applying my function like below in my rmd file

col_name <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
label <- c("Sales","Ops","admin","HR") 

fac_conv_lapply(data = ldat,col_names = col_name, labels = label )
```

Error:  Error in paste0("factor(", col_names[[x]], ",labels=c('", paste0(labels[[x]],  :
object 'col_names' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work move `fac_conv` into `fac_conv_lapply`:

```r
# Sample Data Frame
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data$col5<-factor(data$col5, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Local","Overseas"))

df<- data
df$cc1<-1
df2<- subset(df, col5 == 'Local')
df$cc2<-ifelse(df$col5 == 'Local',1,NA)
lst<-list(df$cc1, df$cc2)
ldat<-list("ALL" = df, "Local" =df2)

fac_conv_lapply <- function(data,col_names,labels) {
  
  fac_conv <- function(x) {
    paste0(
      "factor(", col_names[[x]],
      ",labels=c('",
      paste0(labels[[x]],
             collapse = "','"
      ), "'))"
    )
  }
  
  list_of_fac <- purrr::map_chr(seq_len(length(col_names)),
                                fac_conv)
  ldat <- map(data, ~  {
    .x[col_names] <- map2(.x %>% 
                            dplyr::select(col_names), 
                          labels, ~ factor(.x, labels= .y))
    .x} )

  ldat
}

col_name <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
label <- c("Sales","Ops","admin","HR") 

ldat1 <- fac_conv_lapply(data = ldat, col_names = col_name, labels = label )

lapply(ldat1, head)
#> $ALL
#>    col1 col2  col3 col4     col5 cc1 cc2
#> 1 Sales  Ops admin   HR    Local   1   1
#> 2 Sales  Ops admin <NA> Overseas   1  NA
#> 3  <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA>    Local   1   1
#> 4  <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA>    Local   1   1
#> 5  <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA>    Local   1   1
#> 6  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> Overseas   1  NA
#> 
#> $Local
#>     col1 col2  col3 col4  col5 cc1
#> 1  Sales  Ops admin   HR Local   1
#> 3   <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA> Local   1
#> 4   <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA> Local   1
#> 5   <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA> Local   1
#> 7   <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> Local   1
#> 10  <NA>  Ops  <NA> <NA> Local   1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, my preferred solution would be to rewrite `fac_conv` as a two argument function

```r
fac_conv <- function(x, y) {
  paste0(
    "factor(", x,
    ",labels=c('",
    paste0(y,
      collapse = "','"
    ), "'))"
  )
```

and call it like so:

```r
list_of_fac <- purrr::map2_chr(col_names, labels, fac_conv)
```

**EDIT** Not sure what you mean by it'

Comment: its not working for me , actually input parameters should be 
( data = ldat , col_names = col_name , labels = label )
input data will always be ldat for the function

Comment: so the requirement is the function should not work directly for data but to ldat(list of data frames).
i am unable to create it for ldat.

Comment: Hi @sanuali0123. I just made an edit and edited the full code including the output when applying the function to your list of dfs.

Comment: one more thing , I also have one more approach but unable to create function with that , question is same but  that is simple approach . can you help me to create function with that also
for( i in seq_along(ldat)){
  ldat2[[i]][] <- lapply(names(ldat[[i]]), function(x) factor(ldat[[i]][[x]], labels = faclist[[x]]))
}